# PHP Session Vulnerability

Tags: php, vulnerability, session-management, time, ctf

I'm trying to solve a challenge on a CTF, with PHP sessions.
The goal is to make `check.php` echo `$_PASSWORD`.

***I do not have access to the files themselves, and therefore I cannot edit them.***

My proposed solution is:

1. We want the session to be locked for 20 seconds, therefore we need to make `eat.php` run that much time.
2. At the same time, we need to run `check.php`, having it set `$time` and then wait for the session to be unlocked.
3. Now we need to unlock the session, which means we need to stop `eat.php`.
4. `check.php` will continue running, the following expression: `$time+20!=$_SESSION['time']` will be false, and PHP will echo `$_PASSWORD`.

Is my proposal possible? If it is, how would you implement it?
I'd also like to hear about other directions for solving this problem.

**get.php:**

```
<?php
setcookie('id',uniqid());
?>
```

**eat.php:**

```
<?php
$cookie=$_POST['cookie'];
session_save_path('/home/mawekl/timetravel/');
session_start();
echo 'You ate: '.htmlspecialchars($cookie);
echo "\n<br>";
$_SESSION['cookie']=$cookie;
$_SESSION['time']=time();
?>
```

**check.php:**

```
<?php
$cookie=$_COOKIE['id'];
$time=time();
session_save_path('/home/mawekl/timetravel/');
session_start();
if ($cookie!=$_SESSION['cookie'])
    die('Wrong cookie');
if ($time+20!=$_SESSION['time'])
    die('You must eat cookie after 20 seconds from now, but you ate it '.($time-$_SESSION['time']).' seconds ago');
echo $_PASSWORD;
?>
```

Comment: Do you have access to the files?

Comment: I thought I was pretty clear about that.. No access whatsoever

Comment: Do you have *any* access to the server? If you can deploy *other* scripts or code accessible via the webserver then blocking the session and hence the execution of check.php at session_start() is trivial. But in most such scenarios you could read the code and hence the value represented by $_PASSWORD directly.

Comment: Negative, as OP mentioned in the post.

Comment: Op only said they had no access to these files.

Comment: I can only send requests to theses pages.

Comment: a. Are these request all served from the same server? Or is it possible one server has a slow clock? b. How do the eat.php response times vary to a very large value of $_POST['cookie']?

Comment: Why can't you call `eat.php` and then call `check.php` 20 seconds later? Is the session discarded if you do that?

Comment: @Sjoerd You misread the challenge. The challenge is to have the cookie set 20 seconds INTO THE FUTURE.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong of course, since I don't know the solution, but here's my analysis.

`get.php` can be completely ignored, as you can make up a random `id` cookie value.

We might not have all the necessary information. Does the server run Apache or something else? Which PHP version was used? Is there a description for the challenge (they often contain obscure hints)?

As it stands, I see only two realistic ways of approaching this that: injecting data into that `$_SESSION['time']` variable, or making `check.php` pause after `$time=time();` and before `$time+20!=$_SESSION['time']`.

Looking for injection vulnerabilities in PHP, I only found CVE-2006-3016 (PHP 5.1) but it contains very few details and they'd have to run a very old PHP version anyway. Last year someone also [reported a session injection vulnerability](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71101), but it seems not to be applicable. This avenue does not seem very feasible.

This leaves the pausing trick. I was thinking of something like this:

1. Open a lot of connections and let them request `eat.php` with large `$_POST['cookie']` values to make it take a lot of time to write all the sessions.
2. Request `check.php`, which will hang until step 1 is complete. Vary the amount of requests done in step 1 until it takes exactly 20 seconds.

This would require the server to do multithreading, since it needs to leave `check.php` in a sleeping state and perform a bunch of `eat.php` requests in the background.

The issue with this is that each `eat.php` needs to write to the same session, or it wouldn't block at all in `check.php` (since there would be no thread locking the session that `check.php` tries to read). But if each successive `eat.php` completion updates the `$_SESSION['time']` value to something more recent, it is not going to have an old time value. So this does not work either. (It could perhaps work if PHP blocks on *any* session still being written to, then another session could be updated in `eat.php` and still leave `check.php` hanging, but this seems unlikely so I haven't explored the possibility.)

In short, we need more information and perhaps even access to a challenge environment. From my perspective, it seems impossible without another vulnerability (e.g. sending false NTP updates).

### To answer your question

Yes, your proposed solution would probably work. Just one issue: how would you actually manage to make it do this? ;)